# ExtJS : handling browser exit event (click on cross-exit)

Tags: javascript, extjs, browser, dom-events

I would like to know if there is any way to handle the browser exit event.

For example, I would like to send a query when the user click on the cross-exit or simply close his browser.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This thread might shed some insight:
http://forums.devarticles.com/javascript-development-22/how-to-stop-browser-from-closing-using-javascript-8458.html

I haven't given this solution a test-run yet. But it seems possible.

Here's a more in-depth discussion on the `onbeforeunload` event handler.
http://bytes.com/topic/javascript/insights/825556-using-onbeforeunload-javascript-event

And then there's always [quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/index.html). Unfortunately the load/unload events are not yet covered by quirksmode. As stated on the page:

> I haven’t tested the load and unload events yet; they’ll be added to the table later on.

Answer (score 16):

I think I have found a solution. I haven't tested it on IE but it seems to be working on Firefox :

```
Ext.EventManager.on(window, 'beforeunload', function() {
    alert('cross-exit tab click AND cross-exit browser click');
});

Ext.EventManager.on(window, 'unload', function() {
    alert('cross-exit tab click');
});
```

PS : Thank you exhuma for having edited the question ;)

Comment: FYI: this works only on browser refresh. Doesn't work when the page "unloads" because of browser (Chrome) Back or Forward buttons. Still good to know, thanks.