# Registering Window Unload in extjs mvc

Tags: extjs4, extjs-mvc

Do anyone have an idea about, how to register the window unload event in an ExtJS MVC application.

```
Ext.EventManager.on(window, 'beforeunload', function() {
alert('cross-exit tab click AND cross-exit browser click');});
```

The above code needs to be placed in a javascript file. I'm not sure which file should carry the above code.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2808840/extjs-handling-browser-exit-event-click-on-cross-exit,                                  the above url shows registering for window unload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
return "You have made changes, are you sure you would like to navigate away from the page?";}.bind(this);
```

The above code does the job. I placed it under my main controller.

Comment: http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?109373-SOLVED-Confirm-navigation&highlight=window+unload  from sencha forum helps.

Answer (score 0):

Put it in controller just inside init method:

```
init: function(){

Ext.EventManager.on(window, 'beforeunload', function() {
    this.setAllValues(false);
});

this.control({
............
....
```

Comment: I've tried this and put it under init of application, but it's not working